# Trying to access the key and values of a nested JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, nested, key-value

I am trying to comsume bill.json through accessing all of the JSON keys and values, unfortunately I do not get an error message so I am stumped

please look at the following JSON

```
{
 "statement": {
"generated": "2015-01-11",
"due": "2015-01-25",
"period": {
  "from": "2015-01-26",
  "to": "2015-02-25"
    }
  },
  "total": 136.03,
  "package": {
  "subscriptions": [
  { "type": "tv", "name": "Variety with Movies HD", "cost": 50.00 },
  { "type": "talk", "name": "Sky Talk Anytime", "cost": 5.00 },
  { "type": "broadband", "name": "Fibre Unlimited", "cost": 16.40 }
],
"total": 71.40
},
"callCharges": {
"calls": [
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
  { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 }
],
"total": 59.64
},
"skyStore": {
"rentals": [
  { "title": "50 Shades of Grey", "cost": 4.99 }
],
"buyAndKeep": [
  { "title": "That's what she said", "cost": 9.99 },
  { "title": "Brokeback mountain", "cost": 9.99 }
],
"total": 24.97}}
```

---

and the following HTML and JS code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="statementHdr"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('bill.json', function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(resultJSON);
            var statementHdr = "<ul>";
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    statementHdr += "<li>" + key + "---" + data[key] + "</li>";
                }
            }
            statementHdr += "</ul>";
        })
        document.getElementById("statementHdr").innerHTML = statementHdr;
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `resultJSON`? You already *have* `data`, which should be a parsed-and-ready-to-go JavaScript object.

Comment: Also, are you sure `bill.json` is in the same folder as the web page? Are you running this from a server, or just loading the page locally in the browser?

Comment: It's difficult to understand how that code could possibly *not* result in errors on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Since your bill.json is a json file, you dont need to use JSON.parse, You can directly access it's values. use below code to understand it. Also you cannot directly display data[key], because some values also containing another array of data, so you need to get them separated to display. If you display them, you will get [object Object]. So you need to indicate their key or you need to iterate it again inside that array to get those information.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="statementHdr"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('bill.json', function(data) {
            var statementHdr = "<ul>";
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                statementHdr += "<li>" + key + " --- " + value + "</li>";
            });
            statementHdr += "</ul>";

            $("#statementHdr").html(statementHdr);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some small issues in your code. I have fixed them so you can learn each part, but some more improvements other than the ones I will list can be made to improve your code readability and reliability.

**The first** step is that as you are loading a json with `$.getJSON` you don't need the `JSON.parse`. Also at this same part there is the usage of a `resultJSON` variable that was not instantiated.

**The second** step is that your HTML insert is outside the $.getSON callback, in thi case you just need to move the `document.getElementById("statementHdr").innerHTML = statementHdr;` call or even enhance it with a `$("#statementHdr").append(statementHdr);` jQuery method.

**The third** step is that even after this changes your code will show some `[object object]` because some times when you use `data[key]` it is in fact a nest JSON object. In this case you can navigate into the nested object or just use a `JSON.stringify` to show the content.

The code bellow is already changed to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('bill.json', function(data) {
            var statementHdr = "<ul>";
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    statementHdr += "<li>" + key + "---" + JSON.stringify(data[key]) + "</li>";
                }
            }
            statementHdr += "</ul>";
            $("#statementHdr").append(statementHdr);
        })
    })
```